# ImageView Never Appears In Android LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm not sure why... but I have an imageView (ic_launcher) which never seems to appear in my layout and I'm not sure why this is happening in this instance...

Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

### XML:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_store_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_store_icon"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100sp"

            android:padding="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
                android:id="@+id/star_rating"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:progressTint="@color/primaryColorDark"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:numStars="4"
                android:stepSize="0.2"
                android:rating="2.0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isIndicator="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />



    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please correct your XML code. Nothing is clear. There is 2 lines of code above. What are they ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify any drawable to that image.

```
android:src="@drawable/your_img"
```

Answer (score 0):

check my comments

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play_store_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" /> 
 </FrameLayout>

  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"  // change this wrapcontent
android:layout_height="match_parent"// change this wrapcontent
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_store_icon"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100sp"

        android:padding="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
            android:id="@+id/star_rating"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:progressTint="@color/primaryColorDark"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:numStars="4"
            android:stepSize="0.2"
            android:rating="2.0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isIndicator="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi AndroidExterminator

You are setting the id for an imageView not background or drawable resource id.

Change this lines

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            />
```

to

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            />
```

or

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            />
```

or @mipmap/ic_launcher accordingly

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as your Root ViewGroup? LinearLayout or Relative or Frame? Because this may cause the problem... as you are setting all the widths and heights to **matchParent** The front view might be hiding the view below if its FrameLayout as root or Relative.